# DBFlow - update multiple items efficiently

Tags: android, database, dbflow

ArrayList list =... --> Get data from database

//do some changes in the values of the objects in the list

for(MyObject object:list){
    object.save();
}

Instead of this for loop is there a way to save multiple items that is more efficient than calling save() a bunch of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly found it

```
FlowManager.getModelAdapter(MyTable.class).saveAll(myObjectsList);
```

and it's faster than calling save multiple times. From some quick testing for 15 items the multiple save took an average of 120 milliseconds while saveAll took about 100 milliseconds. percentage wise it's quite a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `save()` multiple times is ok. If there is a thousand entries, you can do it with [asynchronous transaction](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/StoringData.html) to avoid blocking UI.

If you really want to do save one time, create a new table(model) name `ListObject`, then use the relationship one-to-many to store it as a `List<Object>`. So have to save one time only. 
https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/Relationships.html

Comment: there is a way after all..thnx for pointing me to the documentation i hadn't found that before. i posted the answer below

Comment: yah, glad you found the answer